# React.js and MySQL Resulting in node/no-deprecated-api Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

Trying to build a backend database for my React app, and upon trying to import the relevant MySQL libraries, it throws an error. There are no problems when I run it from the terminal, but the moment I put it in, I receive the following error:

./src/data/node_modules/mysql/node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js
  Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'node/no-deprecated-api' was not found  node/no-deprecated-api

Have not been able to find any solutions while searching.

My code:

```
import {mysql} from 'mysql'; // Commenting out this one line stops the error

export default function tester() {
    /*
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({ // Commented out only when import is commented
        host: 'localhost',
        user: '<username>',
        password: '<password>',
        database: '<db name>'
    });
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Connected!');
    });
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone reading this in the future, the solution was to not connect directly to the MySQL server, instead to use Express.